# Send packet via socket c# to php conversion

Tags: c#, php

I can barely understand C# and I know little in PHP sockets.

I'm translating the code below to send a text packet from the below c# code into php.

```
Socket Client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            try
            {
                Client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ServerBox.Text), int.Parse(PortBox.Text)));

                byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MessageAnnouncementBox.Text);
                List<byte> pack = new List<byte>();

                pack.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)(5 + message.Length)));
                pack.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)11));
                pack.AddRange(message);
                pack.Add(new byte());

                NetworkEngine.Send(Client, pack.ToArray());
                NetworkEngine.Send(Client, pack.ToArray());

                Client.Disconnect(true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Fatal Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);   
            }
```

I tested with the very basic I know in PHP socket

```
<?php
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

    $msg = "5 This is a test announcement";
    $len = strlen($msg);

    socket_sendto($sock, $msg, $len, 0, '127.0.0.1', 15010);
    socket_close($sock);
?>
```

And it got me to an error. Any suggestion would be great. TIA